# Linear independence confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following result:

> The set $\{\mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_n\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if some $\mathbf{v}_i$ is a linear combination of its predecessors. That is, $\mathbf{v}_i \in$ span$\{\mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_{i-1}\}$ for some $i \in \{1,...,n\}$

I was curious what happens in the case where $\mathbf{v}_1$ is the zero vector and $\mathbf{v}_2,...,\mathbf{v}_n$ are linearly independent. This set is linearly dependent and I think you can say the second sentence in the above statement is true since the predecessors of $\mathbf{v}_1$ is the empty set and the span of the empty set is the zero vector. But I'm unsure about the first sentence. Can you have a linear combination of the empty set?

Comment: When you wrote “some $\mathbf v_1$”, I suppose that you meant “some $\mathbf v_i$”.

Comment: The textbook you are using may (?) exclude the $0$ vector from being included. Otherwise, the book may include something about all possible permutations.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Also I think that. I think is a typo.

Comment: As given, the result is false. Either once must not include the zero vector as the beginning one, or else the wording mustbe changed. For example, for any non-zero vector $\;v\;$ in some linear spacve, the set $\;\{0,\,v\}\;$ is l.d., yet there is no vector which is a linear comb. of the preceeding one...unles, of course, one could take, for the first vector, the empty set....then, under this agreement, the result would be true.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos, Yes, it was some v_i rather than v_1

Comment: @Clayton, the result is stated as given. The proof seems to ignore the case I've described (And DonAntonio describes).